Blank space left behind in the stack by PushReplacement method (Flutter)
The problem was encountered in an android project.

I navigate from screen1 to screen2 with the Navigator.push method.
Then from screen2, I move to screen3 with the Navigator.pushReplacement method.

When I press back button at screen3, the first button press is ignored and the second button press takes me to the screen1.
It is evident from the response of the back button that, there is an empty slot in the stack. If I call Navigator.pop after Navigator.pushReplacement the problem get resolved but momentarily it goes to the screen1 before it shows the screen3.
Here is my code to got to the screen2 (Notification) from screen1 (HomeScreen)
onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Notifications())
            );
          },

Code to go from screen2 to screen3
void moveToUserYscreen({
 required BuildContext context,
 required Contact contactY,
 bool replace = false,
}) {
 int initialTabIndex = 0;
 
 if (contactY.interacted != null && contactY.interacted!) {
  // Set initialTabIndex
  initialTabIndex = 1;
 }

 // Register activeUid in the CloudData object
 CloudData.activeUid = contactY.uid;

 if (replace) {
   Navigator.pushReplacement(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(
     builder: (context) => UserYscreen(
       contactY: contactY,
       initialTabIndex: initialTabIndex,
     ),
    ),
   );
  // Navigator.pop(context);
 }

 Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => UserYscreen(
     contactY: contactY,
     initialTabIndex: initialTabIndex,
    ),
  ),
 );
}


Please provide your code for us to look at

I have edited my question with the code. I am sorry for the delay. Any help is appreciated.

please provide screen2 full code

I believe there is a little problem in your logic,
In this particular code, you are missing 'return' statement which is why your first back click is being ignored. If replace is true, then after doing pushReplacement you have to return / break the flow of this function.
if (replace) {
   Navigator.pushReplacement(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(
     builder: (context) => UserYscreen(
       contactY: contactY,
       initialTabIndex: initialTabIndex,
     ),
    ),
   );
   // Navigator.pop(context);
   return ; //<<ADD THIS
 }

 Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => UserYscreen(
     contactY: contactY,
     initialTabIndex: initialTabIndex,
    ),
  ),
 );
}


Adding the return command worked, thanks Muhammad Hussain
